# Algorithm to represent a number

Tags: algorithm, binary, numbers, bit-manipulation, bit

want to save the number `x` in more bits than the standard binary representation. The bitstring representation, which iam searching, must be unique for this number `x` that i can map `x` to this representation and back. Also on every bit position `1 and 0` must be allowed.

Exists such a bitstring representation of number `x`, or its not possible to create such representation?

For example the zeckendorf representation is unique but doesnt allow 2 consequtive `1`. If iam cut out the `0` after one `1` the length of the resulting bistring is more or less equal to standard binary representation length, but not longer.

Comment: That's your question, but what have you tried on your own show that

Comment: Why do you think you want this?

Comment: To answer this question you have to define very precisely what "*on every bit position 1 and 0 must be allowed*" means. Also, you should specify whether the code words have a fixed length (for instance 32 bits) or how to treat uniqueness for variable width code words (without this, even the standard binary representation is not unique. `x=2` can be encoded as `10` or `010` or `0010` or ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a single bit that is the parity of the original number: XOR all of the bits together.  THe mapping is deterministic, unique, and trivially reversible.

In general, any error detection/correction addition will satisfy your posted requirements.

Comment: I don't understand why the zeckendorf encoding isn't a solution to OP's problem but they accepted this solution. I thought OP's problem with the zeckendorf encoding was that there are some bitstrings that are not valid code words (even though they still could be interpreted as regular fibonacci base numbers). The standard binary encoding with checksums added (as proposed in this answer) has exactly the same problem: There are some bitstrings that are not valid encodings of any `x`.

Comment: OPs problem is that the resulting compression is not longer than the binary representation -- in OP's estimation.

Comment: There *must* be bit strings that are not valid encodings: use a simple mapping.  If the bit strings in our new system are all longer than binary -- because binary is dense, mapping 1:1 to the integers -- then anything that employs more bits than binary *must* have holes in the representation.  Most notably, 0 and 1 will not map to any integer.